# How can I protect my pigs so they don't become pigmen?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My pig has just turned into a zombie pigman. I have tried putting them inside, but they still turn into the pigmen!

Comment: Are you sure a pig turned into a zombie pigman? They only turn into zombie pigmen when hit by lightning. Do you maybe have a nether portal nearby? Those spawn zombie pigmen.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie No there is no portal nearby and they are inside a wooden hut. They are definitely pigmen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Lightning only strikes straight down, but [can transform a pig within 3-4 blocks of the lightning strike](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie_pigman). Therefore, to keep your pigs safe from lightning storms, their shed has to be built so that it keeps them at least 5 blocks away from the outside sky. Building a 5 block wide overhang around the shed roof should do it. Alternatively, make your barn so that the pigs are in an inner chamber, with less "volatile" livestock like chickens and cows in the chambers near the walls.

Comment: I love the idea that a barn full of pigs got struck by lightning, and when you opened the door to feed them the next morning, ARGH ZOMBIES! Ripped straight from a Romero movie.

Answer (score 1):

Dig a 5 by 5 hole 10 blocks deep, and build stairs with a door at the top so the pigs wont get out. Put torches so no mobs can spawn, and build a roof out of any material except wood.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the lightning. You should probably put your pigs underground if it happens a lot. It never happens for me though. Not once. But try putting them underground, or just keeping them indoors, so lightning doesn't hit them.